# How to get entries of a date greater then x date in Apache Phoenix

Tags: apache-phoenix

I have a column activation_date in Phoenix of type Date, which contains entries like "`2016-06-18 07:00:00.000`",
 how do I do select on same for a date greater then x date:

```
select activation_date from xyz where activation_date > '2017-03-17 07:00:00.000' limit 10;
```

Above query gives error like:

> Error: ERROR 203 (22005): Type mismatch. DATE and VARCHAR for
>   USER_DATA.ACTIVATION_DATE > '2017-03-17 07:00:00.000'
>   (state=22005,code=203)
>   org.apache.phoenix.schema.TypeMismatchException: ERROR 203 (22005):
>   Type mismatch. DATE and VARCHAR for ACTIVATION_DATE > '2017-03-17
>   07:00:00.000'

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue using the `TO_DATE` function:

```
  select activation_date from xyz where activation_date > TO_DATE('2017-03-17 00:00:00.000') limit 10;
```

[TO_DATE](https://phoenix.apache.org/language/functions.html#to_date)